# Show hoverinfo in treemap only for child container in plotly treemap HTML

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly-express

I have created the treemap graph for share market summery, It shows correct information when i hover on child containers but when i hover on the parent container it shows different syntax, i want instead of that syntax some different values or stop hovering on the parent container at all

This is my written whole code.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import plotly.express as px 
import dash_html_components as html
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output 
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import sys
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import date
from dash import Dash, html, dcc 
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame, json_normalize
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio
from numerize import numerize


dash.register_page(__name__,title='Stock Market Summery',path_template="/")

Data_source = "data/dashbaord_ohlc_df_4_processed.csv"
PATH = ['Sector','Symbol']
# PATH = [px.Constant("Market Overview"),'Country','Sector','Symbol','Name','Currency','MarketCapitalization','Earnings_Share','dailyChange%','PE_Ratio%','PEG_Ratio%']
HOVER_DATA = ['Name','Country','Currency','Market Capitalization', 'Most Recent Quarter','PE Ratio%','PEG Ratio%','Earnings Share','Dividend Yield','Operating Margin TTM','Return OnAssets TTM','Return OnEquity TTM','Quarterly Earnings GrowthYOY','Quarterly Revenue GrowthYOY','dailyChange']
value_attribute = 'Market Capitalization'
COLOR = 'dailyChange'
infotext =  "label + percent parent"
Drag_option = ["Dark Theme","Light Theme"] 
Country_option = ["India","Australia","USA"]
Hover_Tmp = '<br>Name:%{customdata[0]}'+'<br>Country:%{customdata[1]}'+'<br>Currency:%{customdata[2]}'+'<br>Daily Change: %{customdata[14]}%'+'<br>Market Capitalization:%{value:0.3s}'+'<br>Most Recent Quarter:%{customdata[4]}' +'<br>PE Ratio:%{customdata[5]}%'+'<br>PEG Ratio:%{customdata[6]}%'+'<br>Earnings Share:%{customdata[7]}%' +  '<br>Dividend Yield:%{customdata[8]}' + '<br>Operating Margin TTM:%{customdata[9]}' + '<br>Return OnAssets TTM:%{customdata[10]}' + '<br>Return OnEquity TTM:%{customdata[11]}' + '<br>Quarterly Earnings GrowthYOY:%{customdata[12]}' + '<br>Quarterly Revenue GrowthYOY:%{customdata[13]}'+'<br>'
dark_theme = {'(?)':'black','India':'#012B1E','USA':'#43010A','Australia':'#981125'}
light_theme = {'(?)':'White','India':'#C4F1EC','USA':'#FFD6E7','Australia':'#0DB261'}
color_scale = "#32a870", "#cc1819" ##012B2E  #43010A
input_date = '2022-10-21'

df = pd.read_csv(Data_source, usecols = ['Name','Country','Currency','Market Capitalization', 'Most Recent Quarter','PE Ratio%','PEG Ratio%','Earnings Share','Dividend Yield','Operating Margin TTM','Return OnAssets TTM','Return OnEquity TTM','Quarterly Earnings GrowthYOY','Quarterly Revenue GrowthYOY','dailyChange','date','Sector','Symbol','DailyChangeTreeMap', 'Condition','Description'])
link_ref = '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:9990/info/{}" class="csv_link" style="cursor: pointer;color:white; " target="_self" rel="noopener noreferrer">{}</a>'
df['Symbol'] = df['Symbol'].apply(lambda item: link_ref.format(item, item, "{}"))

df = pd.DataFrame(df) 


def filter_df(input_date,country_name):
    input_date = datetime.strptime (str(input_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    if country_name:
        df2 = df[(df['date'] == input_date) & (df['Country']==country_name)] 
    else:
        df2 = df
    return df2 


def create_dropdown(option, id_value):
    return html.Div(
        [   
            dcc.Dropdown(id=id_value, options=option,
                     value=option[0], 
                     style = {}
                     ),
        ],
    )


layout = html.Div([
        html.Div(
                children=[html.H1('Stock Market Summary',),
                html.P('''AI predictions, intraday market price action, biggest movers, H1 sectors performance, and more.''',
                )], id="header", className="row flex-display header", style={"display": "flex", "flex-direction": "column"},),
       
        html.Div(
                html.Div(children=[
                    html.Div(
                    children=create_dropdown(Drag_option, "Theme-select"),className="theme_dropdown",
                ),
                html.Div(children=[html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-single',), 
                dcc.DatePickerSingle( 
                    id='my-date-picker-single',
                    min_date_allowed=date(1995, 8, 5), 
                    max_date_allowed=date(2023, 9, 19),
                    initial_visible_month=date(2022, 12, 31),
                    date=date(2022, 10, 21),
                    style={'width':'200px'}
                ) ],className="date_container"),
                    html.Button('Theme', id='btn-nclicks-1', n_clicks=0),
                # dcc.Input(type='checkbox',className="toggle-button"),
                html.Div(children=create_dropdown(Country_option,"dd-output-container"),className="contry_dropdown"),
                    ]),className="primary-navigation row flex-display",id="header", style={"margin-bottom": "25px"}
        ),

        html.Div([
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Graph(id="indicatorr")], className="graph create_container2 twelve columns"),
                    ], className="row flex-display"),

        html.Div([
            html.Div([
                html.H3('Thank You',)],className="footer create_container2 twelve columns",)
            ]),

    ],className="main",id="mainContainer", style = {'backgroundColor':'#3d3d3b', 'textAlign': 'center',"display": "flex", "flex-direction": "column"})



@dash.callback(
    Output('indicatorr','figure'),
    Input("Theme-select","value"),
    Input('my-date-picker-single', 'date'),
    Input(component_id='dd-output-container', component_property='value')
)


def update_output(theme_select, my_date_picker_single,dd_output_container):
    """
        Updating Tree MAp as per filter
    """
    if theme_select == 'Dark Theme': 
        # color_discrete_map=["#ff4d00","#a13023","#21b811"] 
        color_discrete_map=["#ff4d00","#21b811"] 
    elif theme_select == 'Light Theme':
            color_discrete_map=["#DC3714","#C0C0C0","#19BD1B","#474745"] 
    else:
        color_discrete_map=["#ff4d00","#a13023","#21b811"] 

    filtered_df = filter_df(my_date_picker_single,dd_output_container) 
    if filtered_df.empty:
        print("Dataframe is empty") 
        return "DATAFRAME IS EMPTY" 
    else:
        print("NOT EMPTY") 
        indicator = px.treemap(filtered_df,
                    color=COLOR,
                    color_continuous_scale=color_discrete_map,
                    path = PATH, 
                    # template='plotly_white',
                    maxdepth=3,
                    hover_data=HOVER_DATA, 
                    values=value_attribute,
                    color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)

        indicator.update_traces(textfont_size=16,)
        indicator.update_layout(margin = dict(t=35, l=5, r=5, b=5),
                        paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0)',
                        plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0)',
                        # coloraxis_showscale=False
                        )
        indicator.data[0].hovertemplate = Hover_Tmp

        # indicator.data[0].texttemplate ="%{label} %<br>Market Cap.:%{value:0.3s}"
        indicator.data[0].texttemplate ="<b>%{label} </b><br><span class='innertext'>%{customdata[14]} %<br>Market Cap.:%{value:0.3s}"

        return indicator
```

here you can see that it's rendering as a html component, as return method

below code is working as my need, but with pio.show() method & in above code i am not using fig.show

```
fig1 = px.treemap(df, path=['continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))
pio.show(fig1,
         post_script = "/* this works if there is only one Plotly plot on web page */" +
         "setTimeout(function() {" +
         "  el = document.querySelector('div.plotly-graph-div.js-plotly-plot'); " +
         "  /* Plotly event */" +
         "  el.on('plotly_hover', function(d){" +
         "    pth = d.points[0].currentPath;"     +
         "    if(pth === '/' || pth === 'world/') {    /* if root or first root child (a parent) */" +
         "       ght = document.querySelector('g.hoverlayer');"
         "       ght.innerHTML = ''; /* remove hovertext */" +
         "    }" +
         "  });" +
         "}, 200)")
```

i am uploading the screenshots of what i want with the code & what actually i am exprecting

this is homepage

[image]

[image]

This hover i don't want

[image]

This hover only I want

[image]

hover effect only on the child element.

Comment: is it possible that you can provide a sample of your dataframe so we can reproduce your treemap (and the unwanted behavior)? you can copy and paste the output from `df.head(10).to_dict()` into your question